# How to solve right order on x axis in charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have two different datasets with different lengths. The format of both of them looks like:{x: '11:59', y: 2772.33}, {x: '11:59', y: 2770.67}, {x: '12:00', y: 2772.33}... The problem is that the x axis isn´t in the correct order as you can see on the picture. [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jTZg.png)
The script:

````
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                 datasets: [{
                    data: [<?php echo $resultString1; ?>],
                    borderColor: "green",
                    label: "1. Tag",
                    showLine: true
                },
                {
                    data: [<?php echo $resultString2; ?>],
                    borderColor: "blue",
                    label: "2. Tag",
                    showLine: true
                }],
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: true
                    },
                },                
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
              scales: {
                x: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        displayFormats: {hour: 'HH:mm'},
                    },
                    grid: {
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 40,
                          color: 'black',
                          max: 1,
                          min: 0,
                          font: '17'
                    },
                }],
                y: {
                     grid: {
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'left',
                    ticks: {
                        color: 'black',
                        max: 1,
                        min: 0
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        color: 'black',
                        text: 'Leistung (WATT)'
                    },
                },
              },
            }
        });```



I tried to change the format of the datasets but that didn´t solve the problem.
````

Comment: I think the issue is that you are not using a time scale bcause x scale is defined as an array. Instead it should be an object.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in the comment, you `scales` config is not correct.
I have changed it (there were other misconfigs) and the following config should be correct:

```
 scales: {
   x: {
     type: 'time',
     time: {
       displayFormats: {hour: 'HH:mm'},
     },
     grid: {
       color: 'black'
     },
     ticks: {
       font: {size: 40},
       color: 'black',
     },
   },
   y: {
     type: 'linear',
     grid: {
       color: 'black'
     },
     position: 'left',
     ticks: {
       color: 'black',
       max: 1,
       min: 0
     },
     title: {
       display: true,
       color: 'black',
       text: 'Leistung (WATT)'
     },
   },
  },
```